# Org-mode failed to highlight C++ source code when exporting html

Tags: c++, emacs, org-mode

I'm using org-mode V7.8.09. When I was trying to export the following c++ code block to html,

```
#+begin_src c++
  int a=1;
  int b=1;
  printf("%d\n", a+b);
#+end_src
```

it failed with message

```
org-babel-exp processing...
font-lock-fontify-keywords-region: Symbol's value as variable is void: font-lock-end-statement-face`
```

Interestingly, if I claim that it is python code, it exports successfully...

```
#+begin_src python
  int a=1;
  int b=1;
  printf("%d\n", a+b);
#+end_src
```

After I add `(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((C . t)))` in my `init.el`, the error message is gone and c++ codes can be exported to html successfully. But c++ codes are not highlighted, while python codes are highlighted fine.

Comment: funny that a google search for the variable name lists only six results. and all deal with python...

Comment: try using `cpp` instead of `c++`

Comment: already tried c++, C++, cpp, CPP, Cpp, none of these works :-(

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What is your version of Emacs?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Org version 7.8.11, Emacs version 24.

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and see if you can get a stacktrace for the error.

Answer (score 4):

The package that you need load is emacs/lisp/org/ob-C.el

https://bitbucket.org/nobeira/dot.emacs.d/src/c6af5b1535b1/elisp/org-7.4/lisp/ob-C.el.

there is not C++ package

.emacs.el configuration file:

```
(org-babel-load-languages (C . t)))
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

org document:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC cpp   :includes <stdio.h> :exports both
 int a=1;
 int b=1;
 printf("%d\n", a+b);
#+END_SRC
```

for me work (fontify and running) ONLY with cpp source_name

Candido

Comment: Just putting `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` in my `~/.emacs` file works for me on Emacs 24.3.1